# Suppose $a+b+c+d=s$ and $1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d=s$, how can you make any possible conclusions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, partial-fractions

It is known that there is such a number $s$ with real numbers $a,b,c,d$ that are not equal to $0$ nor $1$ and satisfy the following equations.
$$ a+b+c+d=s$$

$$1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d=s$$
$$\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1-b}+\frac{1}{1-c}+\frac{1}{1-d}=s$$
Solve for $s$

The first part of the solution states that if $a,b,c,d$ satisfy the required conditions, so do $\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{b}, \frac{1}{c}, \frac{1}{d}$. Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a}}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{d}}=s$$

Can someone explain to me why? (I'm still puzzled how can you do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put $\frac 1a,\frac1b,\frac1c,\frac1d$ into first two equations you get the same two equations you started with. So if $\frac 1a,\frac1b,\frac1c,\frac1d$ aren't solutions then $a,b,c,d$ aren't solutions as well since either $$\frac 1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac1d\neq s$$
Or
$$\frac 1{\frac 1a}+\frac1{\frac1b}+\frac1{\frac1c}+\frac1{\frac1d}=a+b+c+d\neq s$$

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused, is it like assuming that a=1/a, b=1/b, c=1/c and d=1/d?Are you allowed to make such assumptions?

Comment: @Anonymous Not really,assume the 4-tuple $(1,2,3,4)$ is a solution to first two equations then another solution must be $(1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14)$.A real example could be $(2,2,\frac 12,\frac 12)$ then $(\frac 12,\frac 12,2,2)$ must be a solution.

Comment: But 1+2+3+4 is not equal to 1+1/2+1/3+1/4

Comment: @Anonymous Yes,then $(1,2,3,4)$ is not a solution.You could look at $(2,\frac13,\frac12,3)$ then $(\frac12,3,2,\frac13)$ must also be a solution,hope this helped you.

Comment: I'm not really after the values of a,b,c,d, but rather trying to understand the reasoning behind the a,b,c,d and 1/a,1/b,1/c,1/d as solutions of something. Anyways, I think I'm getting it now. Thanks a lot of man! :-)

Comment: So if the 3rd equation was changed to something else I can still apply the same logic right?

Comment: Yes,you could apply the same logic.